# How to insert lyrics in TuxGuitar?

Tags: software, transcription, tuxguitar

Currently I try to transcribe a song and I want to save the tab with TuxGuitar. For better orientation I want to display the lyrics of the song below the tab like in this image.

[image: Example]

<sub>Image from [makeuseof](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/play-guitar-better-no-matter-how-you-read-music-with-tuxguitar/).</sub>

The website where I found the picture says, that it is possible to enter the lyrics if I press on the lyrics icon, but I am not able to find this button. Does someone know the correct way to enter the text of the song?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 1.2 there is menu item: Track->Lyrics that opens a dialog box, in which you can add/edit the text that appears below the tab(s).  This seems to be the only way to access this feature (no toolbar button or hotkey).

There is a corresponding section in the help documentation that describes how to use this feature.